# Does .net framework 2.0 contain crystal report dlls?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Does .net framework 2.0 contain crystal report dlls or not? I am using vs 2005 crystal report dll and deployed it on windows server 2003 but getting error.....

Which setup(Please provide link) should I run to make crystal reports working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't. You need `CRRedist2005_x86.msi`, IIRC it is copied into the Visual Studio installation directory.

Comment: Can I install from here http://www.filewatcher.com/m/CRRedist2005_x86.msi.16971776.0.0.html

Comment: The forum link contains a reply with the full path to the redist.

Answer (score 0):

No it's a separate install, they should be detected by the dependencies of the Setup. Try refreshing them.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET framework does not contain any 3rd party dlls. These 3rd party tools, like Crystal Reports, are packed with Visual Studio.

When you want to use Crystal Reports on a different pc, you have to install the Crystal Reports Viewer. [Here's some info at the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287928(VS.71).aspx).